# Download File to Specific Directory JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm taking inputs from an HTML form and putting them into a file. I've currently got it so it automatically downloads the file to the downloads folder but I want it to download to a specific directory:
%AppData%/Code/User/snippets/

Here is the code I've got at the moment:

```
function createSnippet() {
    var snipName = document.getElementById('snipName').value;
    var snipScope = document.getElementById('snipScope').value;
    var snipPrefix = document.getElementById('snipPrefix').value;
    var snipBody = document.getElementById('snipBody').value;
    var snipDesc = document.getElementById('snipDesc').value;
    
    // Final
    let CONTENT = (`
{
"${snipName}": {
    "scope": "${snipScope}",
    "prefix": "${snipPrefix}",
    "body": [
        "${snipBody}"
    ],
    "description": "${snipDesc}"
    }
}
    `);

    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([CONTENT], {type: "text/plain"}));
    a.download = `${snipName}.code-snippets`; // I want this to download to the directory shown above
    a.click();
}
```

Comment: To save data to the users hard drive via client side script would require the user to navigate and choose the same space. Could you solve this goal with cookies, local storage, or a db?

Comment: JavaScript can't specify where the file is downloaded to. The user has to select it from a file save dialog.

Comment: @Barmar Why would JavaScript have anything to do with this? JavaScript is a language. It can't either render HTML, or render images, or display videos, or navigate a link, or fetch a resource, or do anything that nonetheless browsers are meant to do. In node.js you can actually specify where the file is downloaded to, JS is not the limitation.

Comment: 1/2 There is (in Chrome) [an API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestFileSystem) that lets you create a sandboxed file-system accessible only from your browser. There are a few APIs that let you store data locally in your browser (Storage + IndexedDB).  There is (in Chrome) [an API](https://wicg.github.io/file-system-access/) that lets your users choose what directory on their disk they give access to your scripts. But moreover, there are settings in your own browser that let you change the directory where it saves files (`chrome://settings/downloads`).

Comment: 2/2 It seems that you're actually only after the latter, but it's not clear from your question.

Answer (score 0):

Using JS, this cannot be done. If your trying to download a file to specific destination in the `drive` it is not possible. This possess a huge security risk if browsers allow it.

When a user is viewing a website, they are using a browser to access the webpage and browser decides what all permissions a website can have and what limitations it should put.

The only way that you download a file in specific folder is,the user doing to himself. Otherwise downloads made by browser will be stored at some default destination like `/user/Downloads` or user chosen path `/user/Downloads/Chrome_Downloads`.